# How to display thumbnails for images on search results in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search-results, image-display

SharePoint newbie here. When I search for files there are thumbnail/previews for word documents, excel spreadsheets, PowerPoint slides, and pdf files. These result types seem to be fine, but not images.

There doesn't seem to be thumbnail/previews for image files in the search results. The files are located in a Document Library not a Picture Library.

I've tried googling and it may have to do with "Search Result Types" under Site Collection Administration inside Site Settings, but I'm not sure what to modify.

Please advise. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is a screenshot of a search result that doesn't provide a thumbnail/preview of the image.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's by design that images don't render thumbnails from a Document Library.

You could vote this on user voice:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/32281756-add-preview-and-thumbnail-features-to-document-lib

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a way. In the meantime, I created a Picture Library and stored images there. The odd thing is I was able to search for images in the Picture Library when it's not in a separate folder. When there are images in folders inside the Picture Library, for some reason, they do not come up in the search. Thoughts? Thanks again for the reply. @Michael Han_MSFT

Comment: Per my test, I can search the images in folders inside the Picture Library. You may need to wait for some time after uploading the image.

Comment: I created a new folder and copy the files from the old folder. The files in the new folder showed up in the searches. Just odd it wasn't showing up in the old folder.
Thanks again.

Comment: It's by default that search will remove duplicate search results.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/online-admin/near-duplicate-items-are-not-listed-in-search-results

Answer (score 0):

use `DefaultEncodingURL` MMD, you need to alter the display template to bring and use it.